# Merge Request Job stuck in Gitlab Pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, merge-request

This job is stuck because of one of the following problems. There are no active runners online, no runners for the protected branch, or no runners that match all of the job's tags: $RUNNER_TAG

Go to project CI settings

[image: Error Message]

Showing above message when execute Merge Request from other branch to protected branch

And this below image is showing runner options.
[image: Runner Settings]

Below I am mentioned this gitlab-ci.yml code for related to merge request

```
# job to check the build health in merge requests
build_check:
  image: node:18.13.0
  stage: build
  extends: .distributed
  only:
    - merge_requests
  script:
    - export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"
    - npx nx affected --target=build --all --parallel=3

# run the unit tests
unit_test:
  image: node:18.13.0
  stage: test
  extends: .distributed
  script:
    - npm run test:web
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/coverage/
    reports:
      coverage_report:
        coverage_format: cobertura
        path: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/coverage/**/**/cobertura-coverage.xml
  only:
    - develop
    - merge_requests
```

Comment: There must be something else in your pipeline definition. Look's like you're using  `$RUNNER_TAG` for tags but the variable is not replaced by it's value and thus no runner found.

Comment: Could come from the jobs you're extending maybe.